# Two repositories for the same application with differents sets of features

Tags: github

I have an application that I need to have two different versions with different features but I wish to have the second version up-to-date with the first one.

To be more explicit, my first application is open-source (Apache License 2.0) and the second is closed source. The second version is a centralized version of the first one (so the user can install the first one freely with all features of the online version, or create an account on the online version, but some features must be paid)

But the online version will have some features that doesn't need to be included in the first one (like a registration page for example)

Is there a way to do easily keep the online version up-do-date with the open-source one using GitHub ? And since the first one is open-source and allow contributions, is it ok to close some part of the source-code that could have been contributed by others ?

Edit for clarification:

This would probably need to be on two different repositories, but if there is an easy way to do this on a single one, that would work too. (But I don't think that's possible since the second online version would need to be closed source)

Comment: Maybe look into using branches?

Comment: How would that work since those are two differents repositories ?